# Is there any function for finding when app is killed from the multitasking bar when the app state is suspended?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to clear the app data when the user removes the app from the app switcher by swiping up after the app is kept in the background about 3 to 4 hours.

Is there any function or delegate to know when the app is killed without coming into the foreground.

I want the login page to be open when the user kills the app from the app switcher. Otherwise, it should open the home page.

Comment: Just show login screen in didFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for Swift:

In your AppDelegate.swift File add the following function (if not present):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // clean your apps data here
    cleanAppData()
    //show the login
    showLogin()
}
```

This function is only called if the app is "cold started".

This means:

- it is called if the app was started for the first time
- if the app was "killed" by iOS
- if the app was "killed" by the user
- it is not called if the app runs in the background and is opened again

Then add the following function (if not present) to AppDelegate.swift:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    // show the homepage
    showHomePage()
}
```

This function is only called if the app is "warm started" which means if the app was running before and sent to the background by the user.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me and saved lots of hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current time in `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(_:)` and `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` to the user defaults. When the app comes back to the foreground or is launching you read this time from user defaults.

Comment: But when app is killed from suspended state, `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` is not called, so how do I handle this scenario?

Comment: You remove the suspension/terminate date when the app comes to the foreground or starts. If the app is killed from suspended state, there will be no date saved from `applicationWillTerminate`. You just check for the existence then.